# javascript prototype loop for in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, prototype, for-in-loop

I am working on a project, which use a lot of "javascript".
I have lot of "ajax" calls, which returns always à "json" array.
For usefull reasons, I created two prototypes of Array object ("in_array" function and "shuffle" function).

Since I did the prototypes, all my "for in" loops are broken (two times showing "undefined" ...)
I looked into google and stackoverflow, and I know my mistake now.
Of course, if I delete my prototypes, the "undefined" go away.

But, I don't find all my answers.

First, I see lot of times, that using "for in" loops are bad, why ?

I develop in "PHP" or "python" too, and I **DO** love "for in" or "foreach" loops.

Secondly, I got a really lot of "for in" loops, so honnestly I prefer changing my prototypes, than changing my loops. Is this that much dirty to switch my prototypes to normal functions, and keep "for in" loops ?

Thirdly, I read that JQuery can correct this bug. My project did got JQuery, what is solution talking about (I only read that JQuery can correct this, not how).

Thank you,

EDIT :
My prototypes code :

```
// FONCTIONS ARRAY
Array.prototype.shuffle = function () {
for (var i = this.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var tmp = this[i];
    this[i] = this[j];
    this[j] = tmp;
}

return this;
}

Array.prototype.in_array = function (needle) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
       if(this[i] == needle)
           return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How did you define your prototype? How are you doing your `for .. in` loop? Did you add the `hasOwnProperty` check? (which skips the prototype). Don't use `for` or `for .. in` in non-framework code, write a map function.

Comment: No, my aim is to try to no add something over all my loops (got more than 50 "for in" in my code.

Comment: Then write a map function.

Comment: what is map function ? Like array_map in PHP ?
How do we do in JS ?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what a map function could look like. I wrote this out of the top of my head so there may be bugs.

```
function object_map(object, callback) {
    var key, ret = {};
    for (key in object) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)) {
            ret[key] = callback(key, object[key]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem occurs:

1. because you're adding (enumerable) functions to `Array.prototype` which will then appear any time you enumerate any array.
2. because you shouldn't use `for ... in` to enumerate arrays, only for enumerating object keys.

If you know you're running on ES5 browsers, you *can* safely add functions to `Array.prototype` using `Object.defineProperty`:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'shuffle', {
    value: function() {
        ...
    }
});
```

which defaults to creating *non-enumerable* properties.